# Adding WPF controls with VB

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I'm new here!

My problem is the following piece of XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Label x:Name="MainText">
        <TextBlock x:Name="DefaultText">
            Application launched successfully!
        </TextBlock>
    </Label>
</ScrollViewer>
<TextBox x:Name="EntryText" KeyDown="EntryText_KeyDown" />
```

I want to add TextBlocks from `EntryText_KeyDown` inside `MainText`. Although it's able to access both `MainText` and `DefaultText` I don't know how I can add an element. Googling seems to provide the C# solution of `MainText.Add` which doesn't seem to be usable(?) in VB.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label can have only one child, so if you want to have multiple textblocks use layout containers like panels, grid

```
<ScrollViewer>

    <StackPanel x:Name="MainText">
        <TextBlock x:Name="DefaultText">
            Application launched successfully!
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel >
</ScrollViewer>
```

Then in code behind you can do:

```
MainText.Children.Add(new TextBlock());
```

If you want to add just one textblock in label then you can do:

```
TextBlock textblock = new TextBlock();
textblock.Text = "My Text";
MainText.Content = textblock ;
```

Comment: you will have to set the Text property like i explained in answer